# How do I pass objects to my Django template?

Tags: python, django

I think what I'm trying to do could be explained as trying to pass all of my Genre objects to my template for display.  I want to display all of my columns and their entries for my Genre model on my template page table_home.
Presently, when I navigate to the table_home.html page, I get
 `NameError at /generators/table_home`
`name 'genre' is not defined`

I want to do the same thing again with the System model when its working.

Can someone explain what is broken with my code and where I can do some reading on passing values from views to templates?  It seems mystical to me and I don't know where to go for self-help, partially because I don't know what terminology to search.

In the table_home view I tried to mimic what was working in both the table view and then what seems to be working in the index view.  Neither worked, and I'm not quite sure why.

My views.py:

```
from tablib import Dataset

from .models import Genre, D100Generator, System

def index(request):
    latest_table_list = D100Generator.objects.order_by('-d_100_id')[:5]
    context = {
        'latest_table_list': latest_table_list
    }
    return render(request, 'generators/index.html', context)

def table(request, table_slug):
    table = get_object_or_404(D100Generator, pk=table_slug)
    return render(request, 'generators/table.html', {'table': table})

def table_home(request):
    global_table_list = D100Generator.objects.order_by('table_name')
    genre_list = get_object_or_404(Genre, pk=genre)
    system_list = get_object_or_404(System, pk=system_id)
    #genre_list = Genre.objects.order_by('genre')
    #system_list = System.objects.order_by('system_id')
    context = {
        'global_table_list': global_table_list,
        'genre_list': genre_list,
        'system_list': system_list
    }
    return render(request, 'generators/table_home.html', {context})
```

This applicable snippet of the table_home.html template dealing with genres:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Genre_id</th>
        <th>Genre name</th>
    </tr>
    {% for genre_id in genre_list %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ genre_list.genre_id }}</td>
        <td>{{ genre_list.genre_name }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}    
</table>
```

Oh, and here are the Models for Genre and System:

```
class System(models.Model):
    system_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    system_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.system_name

class Genre(models.Model):
    genre = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    genre_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.genre_name
```